# Exit code from docker-compose breaking while loop

Tags: while-loop, docker-compose, zsh

I've got case: there's WordPress project where I'm supposed to create a script for updating plugins and commit source changes to the separated branch. While doing this I had run into a strange issue.

Input variable:

```
    akimset,4.0.3
    all-in-one-wp-migration,6.71
```

What I wanted to do was iterating over each line of this variable

```
    while read -r line; do
      echo $line
    done <<< "$variable"
```

and this piece of code worked perfectly fine, but when I have added docker-compose logic everything started to act weirdly

```
    while read -r line; do
      docker-compose run backend echo $line
    done <<< "$variable"
```

now only one line was executed and after this script exited with 0 and stopped iterating. I have found workaround with:

```
    echo $variable > file.tmp
    for line in $(cat file.tmp); do
      docker-compose run backend echo $line
    done
```

and that works perfectly fine and it iterates each line. Now my question is: why? ZSH and shell scripting could be a bit misterious and running in edge-cases like this one isn't anything new for me, but I'm wondering why succesfully executed script broke input stream.

Comment: I'm not sure, but wouldn't this due to the fact that the container runs in the foreground and does not terminate, thus blocking the subsequent `docker-compose run` commands? In this case you could try doing `docker-compose run -d backend echo $line`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this

```
while read -r line; do
  docker-compose run backend echo $line
done <<< "$variable"
```

is that docker allocate pseudo-TTY. After the first execution of docker-compose run (first loop) it access to the terminal using up the next lines as input.

You have to pass -T parameter to 'docker-compose run' command in order to avoid docker allocating pseudo-TTY. Then, a working code is:

```
while read -r line; do
  docker-compose run -T backend echo $line
done < $(variable)
```

### Update

The above solution is for docker version 18 and docker-compose version 1.17. For newer version the parameter -T is not working but you can try:

1. -d instead of -T to run container in background mode BUT no you will not see stdout in terminal.
2. If you have docker-compose v1.25.0, in your docker-compose.yml add the parameter stdin_open: false to the service.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the same problem by using a different loop :

```
for line in $(cat $variable)
do
    docker-compose run backend echo $line
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a nearly identical problem about a year ago, though the shell was `bash` (the command/problem was also slightly different, but it applied to your issue).  I ended up writing the script in `zsh`.

I'm not certain what's going on, but it's not actually the exit code (you can confirm by running the following):

```
variable=$'akimset,4.0.3\nall-in-one-wp-migration,6.71'
while read line; do docker-compose run backend print "$line"; print "$?"; done <<<($variable)
```

... which yielded ...

```
(akimset,4.0.3
0
```

(I'm not at all sure where the `(` came from and perhaps solving that would answer *why* this problem happens)

## Working Script

```
for line in "${(f)variable}"; do
    docker-compose run backend echo "$line"
done
```

The `(f)` flag tells `zsh` to split on newlines; the `"${(f)variable"` is in quotes so that any blank lines aren't lost.  If you're going to include escap sequences that you want to *not* be converted to the corresponding values (something that I often need when reading file contents from a variable), make the flags `(fV)`